# result appearing twice in calculator

Tags: javascript

hi everyone i am jonnathan i am trying to create a calculator in javascript and i am following a tutorial on youtube but for some reason if i add 1 and 1 together the result 2 is alerting

```js
var number1 = prompt("Input the first number");
var op = prompt("Input operator")
var number2 = prompt("Input 3rd number")

if (op == "+") {
  if (number1 == "1") {
    if (number2 == "1") {
      alert("2");
    }
    if (number2 == "2") {
      alert("3");
    }
    if (number2 == "3") {
      alert("4");
    }
    if (number2 == "4") {
      alert("5");
    }
    if (number2 == "5") {
      alert("6");
    }
    if (number2 == "6") {
      alert("7");
    }
    if (number2 == "7") {
      alert("8");
    }
    if (number2 == "8") {
      alert("9");
    }
    if (number2 == "9") {
      alert("10");
    }
  }
  if (number2 == "1") {
    if (number1 == "1") {
      alert("2");
    }
    if (number1 == "2") {
      alert("3");
    }
    if (number1 == "3") {
      alert("4");
    }
    if (number1 == "4") {
      alert("5");
    }
    if (number1 == "5") {
      alert("6");
    }
    if (number1 == "6") {
      alert("7");
    }
    if (number1 == "7") {
      alert("8");
    }
    if (number1 == "8") {
      alert("9");
    }
    if (number1 == "9") {
      alert("10");
    }
  }
}
```

twice there are no errors in the console either that i think could help me with this issue

so far the calculator only adds numbers and only does it through 1 ti 9. how can i fix this error?

Comment: Code is very incomplete (your code only allows adding `1` to another digit), but for this specific problem: remove the second large `if` block or prefix it with `else`. Also: if a tutorial is making you write that kind of code, I'd strongly suggest switching tutorials.

Comment: You have two consecutive if statements that are basically the same. `if (number1 == "1") {...}` and `if (number1 == "2") {...}`. The second runs after the first. You could probably remove the second one.

Comment: hi @RobbyCornelissen, i just learned about variables and if statements so far, and alert and prompt, how could i further improve this

Comment: @Andy im sorry but what does the ... mean in the example you sent. sorry am new to coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
if (op == "+") {
    if (number1 == "1")
    {
        if (number2 == "1")
        {
            alert("2");
        }
```

This section is alerting "2" first. And then this section:

```
if (number2 == "1") {
    if (number1 == "1") {
      alert("2");
    }
```

That's why it's appearing twice.
You can write the program as:

```
let number1 = parseInt(prompt("Input the first number"));
let op = prompt("Input the operator");
let number2 = parseInt(prompt("Input the second number"));
if (op == '+')
    alert(number1 + number2);
else if (op == '-')
    alert(number1 - number2);
else if (op == '*')
    alert(number1 * number2);
else if (op == '/')
    alert(number1 / number2);
else
    alert("Please enter a valid operator");
```

Here we used [parseInt()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp), that returns the first integer from a string.

Comment: sorry i am new to coding what does the parseInt do? and also are curly brackets required? i dont see them in your example

Comment: parseInt basically returns the first integer from your input string. For example, if string is "234", parseInt will return 234. Or if the string is "234 hello", then also it will return 234.
Curly brackets are not required if you have only one statement after your conditionals.

Comment: ok i just saw the last line you put in the answer sorry about that tysm!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!